# Text in hyperlink HTML

Tags: html, web

I'm modifing an existing script to genearte an HTML file. Script puts a location (system path) under a hyperlink. But when I try to copy it from the html file, I get additional "https://" at the front of the text.

As example I see this printed in .html file

```html
<td> ERROR massage. Please find the log <a href="/home/user/log">here</a>  </td>
```

But when I do a right click -> copy link address from chrome I get this:
https://home/user/log

I'm not a web developer, so dont know if I use correct tags to get the job done. So, how can I get exactly the text I need?

Thanks

Comment: you are using anchor tags to hold paths belonging to the filesystem but those are intended to be url .. and written like that it gets intended as a url relative to the domain name where the page was loaded from. When you copy that link from a web browser, it gets expanded as an absolute url. To make the trick you should need to implement a very custom strategy to fill the clipboard

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It gives me `file:///home/user/log` which is expected as it has converted the relative URL (with an absolute path) into an absolute URL based on the URL of the HTML document. It doesn't add HTTPS to it. It might do that if you were looking at the HTML document from an HTTPS URL, but then it would include the hostname too.

Comment: Hi @DiegoD. Any other tag that I can use to get the exact text copied to clipboard? One thing that comes to mind is button. But I'm saying that without knowing if its possible. As I said I'm far from web developer.

Comment: Hi @Quentin, you can say that you recreated the issue as the copy didnt give you exactly the text hidden under hyperlink. As I understood from your and other comments, its expected behaviour. In that case Is it possible to get what I need (exactly same text copied) in different way? Different tag perhaps

Comment: Browsers do **not** provide any user interface to get the value of the `href` attribute without any normalisation.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a very farfetched solution, but in case you want to copy to clipboard the exact value of the href attribute of an anchor element, regardless of any uri schema where the page is getting loaded from and ignoring upfront the fact that probably such url should be encoded as `file://` since it's clearly a filesystem path anyway,

a strategy to adopt could be to have an event triggering the appearence of an overlay that will show such information on top of the whole document and that will expect the click of the close button to return to the previous state.

The problem is that it's quite temerarious to change the clipboard data programmatically since there are security rules engaged that depends on too many conditions that we want to ignore here.

So all you would need to do if you are interested to such strategy, would be to add this code somewhere at the end of your document inside a `<script>` tag (and as long as js will be allowed to run in your page).

Here you have to hold the CTRL key while clicking the link, and an overlay will showup echoing the exact value coming from the href attribute of the link clicked. So that you can just copy by yourself in the clipboard. Of course you have to give focus to the document before trying to hold the CTRL key.

```js
let ctrlKeyPressed = false;

document.querySelectorAll('a')
  .forEach(anchor => {
    anchor.addEventListener('click', e => {  
      if(ctrlKeyPressed){        
        e.preventDefault();
        
        const overlay = document.createElement('div');
        overlay.classList.add('overlay');
        
        const container = document.createElement('div');
        
        const urlSpan = document.createElement('span');                  
        urlSpan.innerText = e.target.getAttribute('href');
        container.appendChild(urlSpan);
        container.innerHTML += '<br>';
        
        const close = document.createElement('a');
        close.innerText = 'close';
        close.href = "#";
        container.appendChild(close);
        
        close.addEventListener('click', event=>{
          event.target.closest('.overlay').remove();
        });
        
        overlay.appendChild(container);
        document.body.appendChild(overlay);
      }        
    });
  });
  
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {    
  if (e.ctrlKey && !ctrlKeyPressed){
    ctrlKeyPressed = true; 
    console.log('holding ctrl key');
  }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', e => {      
  if (ctrlKeyPressed){
    ctrlKeyPressed = false; 
    console.log('left ctrl key');
  }
});
```

```css
.overlay{
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  border: solid black;
  background: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  align-items: center;
}

.overlay > div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<td> ERROR massage. Please find the log <a href="/home/user/log">here</a>  </td>
```